# Cross class/file reference compilation in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

I have a class called my_class.  In my_class there is a class called my_port.  my_port is parameterized with one of the parameters being my_class.  The issue is, they're in different files and the default parameter is my_class.  I have a package for both my_class_pkg and my_port_pkg.  If I import my_port_pkg into my_class_pkg, I still wouldn't be able to compile because my_port_pkg still needs to be able to see my_class since it is using that info as well.  How is this cross referencing typically resolved?

```
class my_port#(type T = my_class) extends base_class #(T);
    //code here
endclass
```

and

```
class my_class
    my_port#(something) X;
   //code here
endclass
```

and

```
package my_class_pkg
    import my_port_pkg::*;
    `include "my_class.sv";
endpackage
```

and

```
package my_port_pkg
    `include "my_port.sv";
endpackage
```

Comment: Can you show some code, your description is not very clear. You say in my_checker, there is a class my_port. Do you mean a nested declaration, or a reference. Where is my_checker declared? Where are the import statements? Why doesn't importing my_class_pkg into my_port_pkg work?

Comment: I've updated my original post.  my_class has a declaration of my_port and my_port has a parameterized type that is defaulted to my_class.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Still not enough code. Where are the packages?, where are the imports?, where is my_checker?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I switched the problem description from my_checker to my_class midway through.  I've resolved that and filled out the package info for reference.  my_class IS my_checker.  I just didn't mean to have both written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you not showing more because you actual code is more complex. It's going to be difficult to suggest alternatives.

The main issue is why such tightly connected classes are in two separate packages? If they were in the same package, you could use a forward `typedef` that would address this circular dependency.

Another approach is to break the circular dependency by removing the default `type T = my_class` and just use `type T`.

Comment: so my_port is actually a utility class that is used in several places.  The reason I have it parameterized as my_class by default is because it is my understanding you need to provide some default.  I tried not providing a default for the parameterization and I get compilation errors:  "No override or default value"

Comment: You do not need to provide a default if everywhere you reference the class you provide an override. But if my_port is a utility class that we be used in  several places, doesn't that imply that my_class will also get used in those same several places if it is a default type that does not get overridden?

Comment: No just my_port.  So the testbench has my_class and my_class_2.  Each needs to have a my_port in it.  my_port needs to know the type of class it is in but it can't be static (realistically this isn't just 2 class and this is UVM so the environment is bigger and more dynamic).

Comment: Dave.  I looked at the errors again and you were right, I wasn't overriding the parameters everywhere.  I had a `uvm_component_param_utils(my_port) in the my_port class which didn't have the parameters overridden.  I guess the solution ended up being simple... just don't provide defaults.  I just didn't know you could do that because I wasn't reviewing my errors close enough.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of chicken and egg problem is common in OO design. If everything were in the same package, a *forward type definition* would do the trick:

```
package my_package;

  typedef class my_class;  // this is a forward type definition

  class my_other_class;
    my_class mc;    
  endclass

  class my_class;
    my_other_class moc;
  endclass

endpackage

module my_module;

  import my_package::*;

  my_class mc = new;

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3sbd

With the classes in separate packages, things are a bit more tricky. This seems to work, but is a bit nasty:

**my_class.sv:**

```
class my_class;
  my_port #(base_class) X;
   //code here
endclass
```

**my_port.sv:**

```
typedef class my_class;

class base_class #(type T = my_class);
  //code here
endclass

class my_port#(type T = my_class) extends base_class #(T);
    //code here
endclass
```

**the packages:**

```
package my_port_pkg;
    `include "my_port.sv";
    `include "my_class.sv";
endpackage

package my_class_pkg;
    import my_port_pkg::*;
    `include "my_class.sv";
endpackage
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2gCX

Comment: Do I need to define my_port and my_class in the same package?  my_port is a utility class that will be used in many places so I was trying to keep the sv includes separate.